# Check if user cancelled SKPaymentTransaction

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

How can I check if user tapped cancel button (either when he was asked if he wants to purchase smth or perhaps if he already purchased this SKProduct whether he wants to download it)?

For now I just receive SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed in paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: method both after user taps cancel button and for instance when there is no internet. Any way to differentiate these two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the SKPaymentTransaction `error` property that is set.

> @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSError *error
>
> An object describing the error that occurred while processing the transaction. (read-only)
>
> The error property is undefined except when transactionState is set to SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed. Your application can read the error property to determine why the transaction failed.

Additionally, you may want to use Apple's Reachability class to determine if Internet is available prior to initiating the transaction.

Comment: That's the weird part about it. When I press cancel button I still receive SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed in paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: method and the following error: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Comment: That's unfortunate. So I'd check Internet connectivity using Apple's Reachability class then, and if you do have connectivity, then you know it was either canceled or the purchase failed with the server somehow. I would also file a bug report stating that the error property doesn't work as documented, and ask for a fix.

Comment: This isn't a connectivity issue - for some reason, the error is the same when canceling the transaction or when it fails for any other reason.

Comment: You need to check the error code. The description seems to always be the same. If you look at SKError.h you'll find these values: ``SKErrorUnknown, SKErrorClientInvalid, SKErrorPaymentCancelled, SKErrorPaymentInvalid, SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed, SKErrorStoreProductNotAvailable.`` Check and respond to each appropriately.

Answer (score 25):

This code works for me:

```
if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
    NSLog(@"Other error");
} else {
    NSLog(@"User canceled");
}
```

Comment: which delegate method contains this transaction error?

Comment: You must convert the `transaction.error` to an `SKError` to get the appropriate code.  For example, `if (transaction.error as? SKError)?.code != SKError.Code.paymentCancelled {}`.

Answer (score 15):

Ellen's answer is perfect. Just in case someone is wondering about the other cases

```
switch (transaction.error.code) {
   case SKErrorUnknown:
       //Unknown error
       break;
   case SKErrorClientInvalid:
       // client is not allowed to issue the request, etc.
       break;
   case SKErrorPaymentCancelled:
       // user cancelled the request, etc.
       break;
   case SKErrorPaymentInvalid:
       // purchase identifier was invalid, etc.
       break;
   case SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed:
       // this device is not allowed to make the payment
       break;
   default:
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Swift version:

```
if let error = transaction.error as? NSError {
    if error.domain == SKErrorDomain {
        // handle all possible errors
        switch (error.code) {
        case SKError.unknown.rawValue:
            print("Unknown error")
        case SKError.clientInvalid.rawValue:
            print("client is not allowed to issue the request")
        case SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue:
            print("user cancelled the request")
        case SKError.paymentInvalid.rawValue:
            print("purchase identifier was invalid")
        case SKError.paymentNotAllowed.rawValue:
            print("this device is not allowed to make the payment")
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't cast it to an `NSError` it will remain an `SKError` and you can just do `case SKError.unknown:`; there is no need to use `.rawValue`.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2**

```
if let error = transaction.error,
 (error as? SKError)?.code != SKError.paymentCancelled {
 // Here it is failed for sure!
}
```

Comment: I think more properly you should check for `error.domain` instead of hard casting the object

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski No, this is fine because the expression `(error as? SKError)?.code` will just resolve to `nil` if the cast fails.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 2.2**

In a case where you get a `.Failed` response in the `paymentQueue`, it would be a good idea to handle all the errors you can.

```
if let error = transaction.error {
    if error.domain == SKErrorDomain {
        // handle all possible errors
        switch (error.code) {
        case SKErrorCode.Unknown.rawValue:
            print("Unknown error")
            break;
        case SKErrorCode.ClientInvalid.rawValue:
            print("client is not allowed to issue the request")
            break;
        case SKErrorCode.PaymentCancelled.rawValue:
            print("user cancelled the request")
            break;
        case SKErrorCode.PaymentInvalid.rawValue:
            print("purchase identifier was invalid")
            break;
        case SKErrorCode.PaymentNotAllowed.rawValue:
            print("this device is not allowed to make the payment")
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using Ray Wunderlich's Tutorial Code for in App Purchase. There the Code says:

```
- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {

if ((self = [super init])) {

    // Store product identifiers
    _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

    // Check for previously purchased products
    _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
        BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
        if (productPurchased) {
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]; // CHECK THIS
            [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        }
    }
```

There you can see, that addTransactionObserver is only called, if the Product is already pruchased. If you move this line of code in front of the if query you will get the desired result.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]; // MOVE HERE
if (productPurchased) {
    [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
}
```

In the failedTransaction Method now you can call

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

Now you can check the nil value sent by the Notification in your current view